# Is there way to ignore optional field in terraform module when value is not specified?

Tags: terraform

I'm managing AWS lambda functions with terraform module. Now I want to add `dead_letter_config` to one of the lambda functions, but keep other functions unchanged.

I'm trying to add `dead_letter_config` field (which is optional in `aws_lambda_function` resource) to the module, but I can't find how I can make `dead_letter_config` field available in only a specific lambda function, and make that field ignored in other callers.
My terraform is v0.12.28, so I tried to use `null` default value on a variable.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
...
  dead_letter_config {
    target_arn = var.dead_letter_config_target
  }
```

```
variable "dead_letter_config_target" {
  default     = null
  type        = string
}
```

But `target_arn` field is required under `dead_letter_queue` field, so `terraform plan` fails.

```
Error: "dead_letter_config.0.target_arn": required field is not set
```

Is there any good way to ignore an entire field conditionally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) for that. Basically, when the `dead_letter_config_target` is null, no `dead_letter_config` will be created. Otherwise, one `dead_letter_config` block is going to be constructed.

For example, the modified code could be:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_tf" {

  # other attributes
  
  dynamic "dead_letter_config" {

    for_each = var.dead_letter_config_target != null ? toset([1]) : toset([])

    content {
      target_arn = var.dead_letter_config_target
    }
  }  
}
```

P.S.

For the DLQ, you will obviously need to setup the permissions in the lambda execution role.

Comment: Thanks! This becomes a good chance to learn dynamic block.

Answer (score 2):

The Terraform ["splat" operator `[*]`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) can be used as a convenient way to translate from a value that might be either set or null into either a zero-length or one-element list, which is then more convenient to use with the collection-oriented features of the Terraform language like [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) for example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  # ...
  
  dynamic "dead_letter_config" {
    for_each = var.dead_letter_config_target[*]

    content {
      target_arn = each.value
    }
  }  
}
```